# Are there any examples of group data-sharing using a replicated database, such as CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb, database-replication, crowdsourcing

Background: I am working on a proposal for a PHP/web-based P2P replication layer for PDO databases. My vision is that someone with a need to crowd-source data sets up this software on a web server, hooks it up to their preferred db platform, and then writes a web app around it to add/edit/delete data locally. Other parties, if they wish, may set up a similar thing - with their own web apps written around it - and set up data-sharing agreements with one or more peers. In the general case, changes made to one database are written to another on a versioned basis, such that they eventually flow around the whole network.

Someone has asked me why I'm not using CouchDB, since it has bi-directional replication and record versioning offered as standard. I wasn't aware of these capabilities, so this turns out to be an excellent question! It occurs to me, if this facility is already available, are there any existing examples of server-to-server replication between separate groups? I've done a great deal of hunting and not found anything.

(I suppose what I am looking for is examples of "group-sourcing": give groups a means to access a shared dataset locally, plus the benefits of critical mass they would be unable to build individually, whilst avoiding the political ownership/control problems associated with the traditional centralised model.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out http://refuge.io/
It is built around couchdb, but more specifically to form peer groups.

Also, here is a couchbase sponsored case study of replication between various groups
http://site.couchio.couchone.com/case-study-assay-depot

This can be achived on standard couchdb installs.

Hope that gives you a start.

Comment: That's very helpful - thank you! I've not come across Refuge, but it appears we've been working on a similar idea during a similar timeframe (they're on CouchDB, I'm on PHP/PDO). I really should give their software a spin.

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like Refuge has been around for longer than I'd thought in my previous comment - a few years (judging by the commit history). Are you aware of any examples running Refuge? I think I could really learn a bit more about conflict resolution strategies, so it would be great to see stuff that's worked in the wild.

Comment: There's not much detail to the AssayDepot example, but I guess that it contains a good detail of centralisation. So, not quite comparable to what I'm after, even though it is still an interesting example.

Comment: You asked for "any existing examples of server-to-server replication between separate groups?" The assaydepot example is a real company that uses couchdb's filtered replication between groups. I agree it is light on details.

Comment: The refuge commit history is because it is based on couchdb. You are seeing all of the couchdb commits as well.

Comment: Yes, you're right - I should have emphasised my interest in a completely decentralised approach. Have a tick :0) - your answer was very helpful and will give me a new avenue of research.